# Does this cron expression mean every other Sunday?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

Does the following cron expression mean "execute every other Sunday?"

```
0 0 3 ? * 2/1 *
```

I'm trying to use it with the Spring Quartz scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you are asking about fires at 3 am Monday to Saturday. From [the Quartz Javadoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) you could try using the two expressions `0 0 3 ? * 1#1 *` and `0 0 3 ? * 1#3 *` to execute on the 1st and 3rd Sundays of the month. The `D#N` syntax lets you pick the Nth day D of the month.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it Monday?  Isn't "2" Tuesday? Maybe it's locale-dependent ...

Comment: Check out that Quartz Javadoc I linked to. Quartz goes from 1-7 (Sun - Sat) and Vixie cron goes from 0-7 (Sun - Sun). It seems that is one of the differences between Quartz cron and Vixie cron.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  I think "2/1" means "Tuesday through Sunday."  I'm not sure that it's possible to express "Every other Sunday", because there'd have to be a "week of month" field or something like that.