# Quartz Scheduler: expression to configure the scheduler to execute in the alternative weeks

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Can you please provide the expression to configure the scheduler to execute in the alternative sundays.

Alternatively i tried with the expression `0 0 6 ? * 1#2,1#4` to run in the 2nd and 4th sunday but it fails to trigger

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what scheduler are you talking about ? Please be precise, we got no crystal ball :)

Comment: sorry..it is a quartz scheduler

Comment: Alternatively i tried with the expression " 0 0 6 ? * 1#2,1#4" to run in the 2nd and 4th sunday but it fails to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Trying out your example,

```
JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class)
        .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .build();

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 6 ? * 1#2,1#4"))
        .build();

Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
sched.start();

Date nextFireTime = trigger.getNextFireTime();
System.out.println(nextFireTime);
```

I got the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
CronExpression '0 0 6 ? * 1#2,1#4' is invalid,.
at org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.java:105)
at org.quartz.examples.example3.CronTriggerExample.run(CronTriggerExample.java:66)
at org.quartz.examples.example3.CronTriggerExample.main(CronTriggerExample.java:110)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Support for specifying multiple "nth" days is not imlemented.
at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:483)
at org.quartz.CronExpression.<init>(CronExpression.java:276)
at org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.java:102)
... 2 more
```

So, it is not implemented; whether you patch Quartz to support this use case, or you can use 2 different triggers, one for 1#2 (2nd sunday) , and another one for 2#4 (4th sunday)

**Note : I used the latest quartz, 2.2**

Comment: Thank for the replay Dahanne. But at my side there is no exception raised. it runs perfectly for 2 alternate weeks in the same month but after change the month it did not fired.                        I found the one link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819523/does-this-cron-expression-mean-every-other-sunday. which is similar to my requirement. But there is also no solution. Can anybody answer for this.